# Count repeated numbers in array and return true (Cognitive Complexity)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, eslint

I need to check if a number repeats itself at least three times in an array. How can I refactor it to decrease the Cognitive Complexity that Lint keeps complaining about.

Heres my code:

```
let array11 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]; 

function checkDuplicateNumber (array11) {
     for (let i = 0; i < array11.length; i += 1) {
        let sameNumberLoop = 0;
        for (let i2 = i; i2 < array11.length; i2 += 1) {
          if (array11[i] === array11[i2]) {
            sameNumberLoop += 1;
            if (sameNumberLoop >= 3) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating multiple times, iterate just once, while counting up the number of occurrences in an object or Map:

```js
let array11 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]; 

function checkDuplicateNumber (array) {
  const counts = {};
  for (const num of array) {
    counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;
    if (counts[num] === 3) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(checkDuplicateNumber(array11));
console.log(checkDuplicateNumber([3, 1, 3, 5, 3]));
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. However, I'm a JS newbie and not quite sure how it works. Would you mind telling me what do I have to look for to understand what you've achieved with this line specifically: "counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;". I've never seen the || operator being used that way.

Comment: If `num` hasn't been iterated over before, it won't exist on the object, so `counts[num]` will be undefined. Using `somethingFalsey || somethingElse` will evaluate to `somethingElse`. So the `|| 0` is a way to get the expression before the `+ 1` to be a number. Then add one to the number and assign it to `counts[num]`.

Comment: It doesn't work `checkDuplicateNumber([{}, {}, {}])`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg That doesn't make any sense - the input array should be composed of *numbers*, not objects, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, it's composed of numbers. Thank you for your reply. I'm still trying to figure it out, since I've never seen this approach before. Bu it solved the problem, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array11 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
let array22 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9, 0, 1]

function checkDuplicateNumber(arr) {
  const map = new Map()
  return arr.some((v) => (map.has(v) ? (++map.get(v).count === 3) : (map.set(v, { count: 1 }), false)))
}

console.log(checkDuplicateNumber(array11))
console.log(checkDuplicateNumber(array22))
```